# parameter has incomplete type in C

Tags: c, enums, compiler-errors, incomplete-type

I'm writing some code, when I'm trying to test my code till now, I get an error.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum { add = 0, addu, sub, subu } mips_opcode;
typedef enum mips_opcode mips_opcode_t;

typedef unsigned char byte; // 8-bit int

struct mips {
    char *name;
    byte opcode;
};
typedef struct mips mips_t;

void init (mips_t *out, char *name_tmp, mips_opcode_t opcode_tmp) {
    out->name = name_tmp;
    out->opcode = (byte)opcode_tmp;
}

int main (void) {
    pritnf("no error i assume\n");

    return 0;
}
```

and the error in the commmand-line is:

```
main.c:14:55: error: parameter 3 ('opcode_tmp') has incomplete type
```

Can't I use enums as parameter or what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm surprised it got that far without choking -- it should be giving you an error on the line `typedef enum mips_opcode mips_opcode_t` because `mips_opcode` is a variable, not a type.

Comment: I thought `pritnf("no error")` was the actual joke here...

Comment: It appears you are confusing C and c++. In C a struct definition is **not** a tyepdef.

Comment: @wildplasser: In C++, a struct definition is also not a typedef.

Comment: To expand on Kerrek's comment, see [this Dr. Dobb's article](http://www.drdobbs.com/article/print?articleId=184403396).  In almost all instances, `struct mips` is equivalent to `mips` in C++, except when you have name hiding (which is usually bad practice).

Comment: Yes, after struct `YES { int myintl};` you can use `YES myyes` as a declaration or definition; without the "struct" keyword. (which is similar to a typedef. In Cterms, that is)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It needs to be like this:

```
enum mips_opcode { add = 0, addu, sub, subu }; // type name is "enum mips_opcode"
typedef enum mips_opcode mips_opcode_t;        // type alias
```

Or even:

```
typedef enum { add = 0, addu, sub, subu } mips_opcode_t; // alias of anon. type
```

Don't confuse type names and variables!

(By the way, Posix reserves `_t` suffixes for types, I believe...)

Comment: Yep, POSIX reserves all symbols ending with `_t` in any header file, see the chart in [2.2.2 The Name Space](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_02_02).

Comment: I came across the same error and it was a small typo I couldn't notice make sure you check the spelling twice if you see the error even after trying the above thing

Answer (score 8):

This line is the culprit:

```
enum { add = 0, addu, sub, subu } mips_opcode;
```

You're declaring a variable called `mips_opcode`, of an anonymous `enum` type.

It should read:

```
enum mips_opcode { add = 0, addu, sub, subu };
```

The name of the enum list goes right after the word `enum`.